# I'm trying to change what a text element shows from an integer data type to a string data type when a number is reached

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am very new to SwiftUI and I am coming from a JavaScript background. I was just messing around and i'm trying to make a simple program which just increases the value of the shown number when pressed, then when a certain number is reached the text changes. I've tried so many things but I either get errors complaining about using an instance member in the property initializer or the text listens to the variable, but doesn't change when I want it to. I know this is probably stupid but I am just trying to figure out what is going on here.

heres my very flawed code

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var num = 0
   
    
    var body: some View {
      
        var numShow = (String(num))

        VStack {
            Text(String(numShow))
                .padding()
            Button {
                num += 1
                if (num > 5) {
                    numShow = "test"
                }

            } label: {
                Text("click")
            }

            
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot declare local wrapped variable in result builder. when i add @State to the beginning

Comment: You don't even need `numShow`.  Show your text with `Text(num > 5 ? "test" : "\(num)")`

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand the basics of SwiftUI. Do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

See also: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

You cannot declare something like `var numShow = (String(num))` anywhere you want in SwiftUI. These declarations need to be in special places and in functions.

try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var num = 0
    @State var numShow = ""  // <-- here declared as a String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(numShow)  // <-- here Text takes a String
                .padding()
            Button {
                num += 1
                if (num > 5) {
                    numShow = "test"
                }
            } label: {
                Text("click")
            }
        }
    }
}
```